# Centos 6 - every server gets yum error

Tags: centos, rpm, yum

Since some days, every server gets an error when i try to update by yum or install a package:

YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. $releasever is not a valid release or hasnt been released yet/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/$releasever/base/mirrorlist.txt
Fehler: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base

I tried to clean up yum (yum clean all), deleted the rpm db, deleted the cache from yum, disabled the base repo, nothing is working. I read in an other thread the error is fixable by reinstalling some packages, as rpm says they aren't installed (but they are):
yum --disablerepo=* --enablerepo=c6-media install centos-release yum rpm python python-elementtree rpm-python yum-metadata-parser

Then i get the error:
Error: File from "glob" not found: centos-release*.rpm

If i try to install a package by rpm, eg. centos-release i get the message:
rpm -Uhv http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm
Empfange http://mirror.centos.org/centos-6/6/os/x86_64/Packages/centos-release-6-6.el6.centos.12.2.x86_64.rpm
Error: /var/tmp/rpm-tmp.ZX78Mz: Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD

I'm really getting frustrated, as i didn't made anything on the system before. And now one by another server is getting the same error. Can someone help me?
For my thinking, there have to be an issue with an update from CentOs.
Since this error, Firefox is also not opening any page. Ping to external hosts is working normal.

Example system info:
Linux xxx 2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 17 01:21:03 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
KVM based virtual machine, but also a host running centos 6.5 is affected.

rpm -qa
gpg-pubkey-11f63c51-3c7dc11d
gpg-pubkey-c105b9de-4e0fd3a3
gpg-pubkey-0608b895-4bd22942
gpg-pubkey-ba684223-53a1643c

On the other servers:
rpm -qa
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#    3777 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#    3267 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#    4038 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#    1480 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#     970 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#     460 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#    4046 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#     207 Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#    1488 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
Fehler: rpmdbNextIterator: Überspringe h#    3793 Header V3 RSA/SHA1 Signature, Schlüssel-ID c105b9de: BAD
...

I tried to find a solution by Google, but nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove all repo for your system /etc/yum.repos.d/ and add this repo.

```
#  wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
#  sudo rpm -Uvh epel-release-6*.rpm
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did that, but got the following: Das Paket epel-release-6-8.noarch ist bereits installiert. I have this package on every server installed. When i try do remove it: Fehler: Das Paket epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm ist nicht installiert. It says it isn't installed.

Comment: you go /etc/yum.repos.d folder. and remove manually to remove 

if you facing issue then you copy your error and paste here other wise

Please this site might your issue will be solved 

http://goo.gl/lCYEi1